# Does Google keep the GCM Registration ID always?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am just started to learn the GCM in android. I did not find this in the documentation that Does Google keep the GCM Registration ID always?.

Can a developer remove it, any way to access this database programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides the periodic refresh(which is rare),

> An existing registration ID may cease to be valid in a number of
>   scenarios, including: If the application manually unregisters by
>   issuing a com.google.android.c2dm.intent.UNREGISTER intent. If the
>   application is automatically unregistered, which can happen (but is
>   not guaranteed) if the user uninstalls the application. If the
>   registration ID expires. Google might decide to refresh registration
>   IDs. For all these cases, you should remove this registration ID from
>   the 3rd-party server and stop using it to send messages. Happens when
>   error code is NotRegistered.

About the periodic refresh:

> Note that Google may periodically refresh the registration ID, so you
>   should design your Android application with the understanding that the
>   com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION intent may be called
>   multiple times

Read more:
http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html
http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html#reg-state
[Do GCM registration id's expire?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11590482/do-gcm-registration-ids-expire)

Comment: For all these cases, you should remove this registration ID from the 3rd-party server and stop using it to send messages. How can I get these from my 3rd party server?

Comment: get what from the 3rd party server? Reg Id? 3rd party server has what you sent to it from your application

Comment: and no, for all those cases, there is no "should" remove registration ID from 3rd party server... what are you saying/asking ? please explain a bit more

Comment: How do I know that Google has refreshed the ids and I then should delete it from my database?

Comment: Please check the second link in the answer..reg-state  Also, http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html