# registrationID lifecycle for gcm

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I wonder what is the lifecycle of registrationId(device_token)

```
e.g eD3Fa1yVqx8:APA91bH5gNrC-jhUqaoRwyFLfD2ik4NXwCXohwhm_9CM5hnY9wFwUAOiO_O12Or-dm60sUqy9gN2ZW6mw5i90RyNhb-zHilvtcJczPjZoQlm_4lKNKDejC_1_xiqmYoZnSxaFfVqSA1d
```

How to handle the situation if it's changed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do GCM registration id's expire?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11590482/do-gcm-registration-ids-expire)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as the information on the official docs goes, there is no information about the token being changed by Google. However you should change it periodically.

Quoting https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/registration#automatic-retry-using-exponential-back-off

> Keeping the Registration State in Sync
>
> To protect the client app and app server from potential malicious
>   re-use of registration tokens, you should periodically initiate token
>   refresh from the server. When GCM registration token refresh is
>   initiated from server side, the client app must handle a
>   tokenRefreshed message with the GCM registration client/server
>   handshake.

Comment: I think it's changed after the app updates. Not long time ago my app has been updated and token_device changed

Answer (score 0):

I faced some situations where Registration ID changed. But, i don't know how and when.

So, to handle these situations i updated my app to send Registration ID every time the app is launched. I sent Registration ID with device id and check my database if the registration id changed i updated it.

Comment: good idea. What about saving for specific user the array of registrationIds? I mean, anyway specific user can have several devices, so i think he's gonna have several ids

Comment: yes, if the user has more than one device he will take one registration id for each device. in my case, i replace old registration id with new one.